# What kind of thing did Lummer and Wien use as a 'black body'?

Tags: history, thermal-radiation, blackbody

When I was reading about the experiments on the black body, I was wondering what such a black body would look like. When I google for the black body used during these experiments by Wien and Lummer, I only get graphics.
Did they really just use a black cube with a hole in it, or is it much more complicated? I also read that it took a while to create a black body that could handle temperatures like 1500 degrees.
What were these difficulties to create a perfect black body?

Comment: Without quite answering the question, it might be helpful to know that an alternative name for black-body radiation that was widely used in the early twentieth century was "cavity radiation".

Comment: Here's a photo of the Lummer/Kurlbaum experiment: http://wwwitp.physik.tu-berlin.de/brandes/public_html/qm/umist_qm/node3.html

Comment: Thank you, can you tell if the black body is inside the cylinder, or what is the function of this cylinder?